# Modify elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I've got some elements with the class `.super-elem` that I want to be adjusted somehow, let's say by adding `attribute` to it `adjusted="true"`

I could easily make something like this inside the document's `ready` event :

```
$(".super-elem").attr("adjusted", "true");
```

But I can add `.super-elem` elements later and I want them to be adjusted too.

So when I add `.super-elem` with AJAX, I can use some AJAX callback to make adjustments.

But - there are 1000s of different ways of adding new element to page like just

```
$("<div>").addClass("super-elem").appendTo("body");
```

Is there some way to make sure that any element, any time added or created, that have class `.super-elem` will also have needed adjustments?

My ideas are

- timeout checking if there are elements without adjustments

`setTimeout(function(){ adjust() }, 100);`

- some kind of DOM modified events

But I'm not sure if those are good solutions - I think they are totally bad for performance and also I don't feel the first one is really solid.

Comment: Use the second option bind the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, like: `$("#someDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { //Your code
    });`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent No, don't. The mutation events are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent mutation is not recommended to be used as is stated for example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: Also I've found this about mutation events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events#Performance

Comment: @Kluska000 What do you mean by 'adjustment'..? is it simply css adjustments or something else..?

Comment: I mean any action that you want to be done on some type of element. For example you've got sliders that need some customization, moving some elements, adding navigation basing on content. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `event` that can be triggered every time you `append` or create a new `.super-elem`, e.g. :

```
...
$(".super-elem").append() //or whatever
$.event.trigger("superElemCreate");
..

$(document).on('superElemCreate', function() { 
});
```

Comment: The main and critical point of my problem was that I dont want to trigger it anywhere manually as in some cases (like adjusting stuff from custom plugins etc) it would require a lot of customization.